# Working with shaders using lookup data IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader, gpuimage

I have lookup data provided by one software and I want to use this data with shader as written below:

```
7999745,8000001,8000258,8066051,8066308,8132357,8132614,8198407,8198664,8264457,8264969,8330762,8331019,8396812,8397069,8463118,8463375,8529168,8529425,8595218,8595730,8661523,8661780,8727573,8727830,8793879,8794136,8859929,8860186,8925979,8926491,8992284,8992541,9058334,9058591,9059104,9124897,9125154,9190947,9191204,9257252,9257509,9323302,9323559,9389352,9389865,9455658,9455915,9521708,9521965,9588013,9588270,9654063,9654320,9720113,9720626,9786419,9786676,9852469,9852726,9918774,9919031,9984824,9985081,10050874,10051387,10117180,10117437,10183230,10183743,10183999,10249792,10250049,10315842,10316355,10382148,10382405,10448198,10448455,10514503,10514760,10580553,10580810,10646603,10647116,10712909,10713166,10778959,10779216,10845264,10845521,10911314,10911571,10977364,10977877,11043670,11043927,11109720,11109977,11176025,11176282,11242075,11242332,11308125,11308638,11308895,11374688,11374945,11440738,11441250,11507043,11507300,11573093,11573350,11639399,11639656,11705449,11705706,11771499,11772011,11837804,11838061,11903854,11904111,11970160,11970417,12036210,12036467,12102260,12102772,12168565,12168822,12234615,12234872,12300921,12301178,12366971,12367228,12433277,12433278,12433535,12433536,12433793,12499330,12499587,12499588,12499845,12565382,12565639,12565896,12565897,12566154,12631691,12631948,12631949,12632206,12697743,12698000,12698001,12698258,12698515,12764052,12764310,12764311,12764568,12830105,12830362,12830363,12830620,12830621,12896414,12896671,12896672,12896929,12962466,12962723,12962724,12962981,12962982,13028775,13028776,13029033,13029290,13094827,13095084,13095086,13095343,13095344,13161137,13161138,13161395,13161396,13227189,13227446,13227447,13227704,13227705,13293498,13293499,13293756,13293757,13359550,13359807,13359808,13360065,13360066,13425859,13425860,13426117,13426119,13491912,13491913,13492170,13492427,13492428,13558221,13558222,13558479,13558480,13624273,13624274,13624531,13624532,13624789,13690582,13690583,13690840,13690841,13756634,13756635,13756892,13756893,13757151,13822688,13822945,13823202,13823203,13888996,13888997,13889254,13889255,13889512,13955049,13955306,13955307,13955564,14021357,14021358,14021615,14021616,14021873,14087410,14087667,14087668,14087925,14153719
```

Fragment Shader code:

```
precision highp float;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
 uniform float uAmount;

 void main() {
     vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
     vec2 pos = vec2((color.r + color.g + color.b)/ 3.0, 0.0);
     vec4 dstColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, pos);

     gl_FragColor = mix(
                        color,
                        dstColor,
                        uAmount);
 }
```

Help me to pass this data to `sampler2D inputimageTexture2`.
I am thinking that these should converted to rgb(image texture) somehow, so I can pass this to sampler2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution these lookup data are 32-bit integer type.
Convert 32-bit integer to RGB, then pass RGB array as texture to shader.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that the lookup table is 1 channel and 2D (16x16?).

You could try uploading it with `glTexImage2D` as
`GL_FLOAT` with `GL_LUMINANCE` or `GL_ALPHA` and your shader would become

```
vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).xxxx // GL_LUMINANCE
```

or

```
vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).aaaa // GL_ALPHA
```

This question is tagged as [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), which I don't know at all (so what follows could be completely wrong!), but I imagine it manages its own textures so you may have to ask it to make the LUT available to your shader. Looking through the source, `GPUImageRawDataInput` looks like a good place to start to get your lookup table into GPUImage, maybe with something like

```
GPUImageRawDataInput *rawInput =
    [[GPUImageRawDataInput alloc] initWithBytes:yourTable 
                                           size:CGSizeMake(16, 16)
                                    pixelFormat:GPUPixelFormatLuminance 
                                           type:GPUPixelTypeFloat];
```